# Что собой представляет и для чего используется блокировка «историческое значение»?

Tags: поддержка, faq

Иногда к вопросам применяется блокировка «историческое значение».

- Что собой представляет блокировка исторически значимых вопросов?
- С какой целью применяется блокировка исторически значимых вопросов?
- Каков механизм действия блокировки исторически значимых вопросов?
- Когда целесообразно применять блокировку исторически значимого вопроса, а когда это неприемлемо?
- Как попросить заблокировать исторически значимый вопрос?

---

Свободный перевод публикации «[What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/)»

Answer (score 10):

#### Что собой представляет блокировка исторически значимых вопросов?

Блокирование исторически ценных вопросов – это механизм, с помощью которого модераторы могут отмечать вопросы как исторические артефакты. Вопросы, заблокированные как исторически ценные, имеют следующее примечание:

> ### заблокировано Модератором♦ 16 марта в 20:01
>
> Этот вопрос сохранили по причине его исторической важности, но он не расценивается как хороший вопрос по теме, соответствующей специфике этого сайта, поэтому просим вас не рассматривать его, как подтверждение вашей возможности публиковать аналогичные вопросы. Этот вопрос и ответы на него заморожены, их невозможно изменить. Подробнее: справка.

#### С какой целью применяется блокировка исторически значимых вопросов?

Блокировка вопроса как исторически значимого применяется с целью сохранения устаревшего содержимого, имевшего высокую популярность во время публикации, но в данный момент не соответствующего тематике сайта, на котором он размещен. Подобная блокировка сообщения является окончанием спора о том, должно ли сообщение оставаться на сайте или его следует удалить и часто является окончательным статусом для многократно удаленных, но позже восстановленных вопросов.

#### Каков механизм действия блокировки исторически значимых вопросов?

В дополнение к отображаемому примечанию («историческая блокировка»), заблокированные с данным статусом вопросы «заморожены во времени»: за них нельзя голосовать, нельзя отмечать их флагом, отвечать на них, редактировать и комментировать. Такие вопросы не попадают в стандартные списки вопросов (на домашней странице, странице всех вопросов и списках, отображаемых при поиске по меткам), но все же могут быть найдены поиском слов из заголовка или тела вопроса (с помощью поиска по сайту, поисковиком Google и т. д.). Визуальное представление всего сообщения меняется: исчезают все стрелки для голосования — как у вопроса, так и у всех ответов.

Примечание: Блокировка исторически значимых вопросов на Мета-сайтах не приводит к их исключению из всех списков, хотя ответы на них все же «замораживаются» аналогичным образом.

#### Когда целесообразно применять блокировку исторически значимого вопроса?

Вопросы могут быть заблокированы как исторически значимые, при следующих условий:

1. Сообщение не соответствует тематике сайта или неконструктивно
2. Несмотря на свою нерелевантность, сообщение является крайне значимым для сообщества
3. Имеет большое число просмотров, высокий рейтинг, на него ссылаются другие сообщения
4. Сообщение является источником споров, то есть было хотя бы раз закрыто и вновь открыто, или же хотя бы раз удалено и восстановлено.

#### Когда блокировка вопроса как исторически значимого неуместна?

Вопросы не следует блокировать как исторически значимые, при одном из условий:

1. Активно пополняются информацией
2. Имеют крайне низкую ценность.

Ориентироваться можно на следующий принцип: если вопрос хоть немного не соответствует третьему правилу Джеффа Этвуда из его публикации «[We Hate Fun Here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/)», опубликованного в блоге, вероятно, вопрос недостоин этого статуса. Третье правило гласит:

> Способен ли этот вопрос научить меня чему-то новому, что я смогу использовать, чтобы еще лучше делать свою работу? Могу ли я что-либо из него узнать?

#### Как попросить заблокировать исторически значимый вопрос?

Отметьте вопрос сигналом тревоги, чтобы привлечь внимание модератора, выбрав параметр «свой вариант описания». В описании тревоги объясните, почему вы считаете данное сообщение исторически значимым. Модератор оценит вопрос в соответствии с вышеупомянутыми критериями и либо заблокирует его, либо отклонит тревогу с объяснением причины.

Как вариант, если вы хотите попытаться получить бóльшую поддержку сообщества по тому или иному вопросу, либо оспорить решение модератора, вы можете [опубликовать вопрос здесь, на Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Идеологически, блокировка вопроса, как исторически значимого, означает, что вопрос не должен изменяться ни на йоту.