# Заморозить процесс сжигания меток

Tags: предложение, удаление-метки, нытьё, удаление-ответов

Я примерно конечно догадываюсь, чем все это закончится, но путь надо пройти до конца.

Вопрос инициирован обсуждением топика [Да сколько же можно работать](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5799/%D0%94%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C), по следам которого случился [батхерт в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39826016#39826016)

Кому лень втыкать, телеграфирую одним абзацем:

1. Группа активистов после некоторого обсуждения приняла решение, что есть метки не очень совместимые с кодексом ruSO
2. После чего были предприняты некие технические действия которые условно назовем **сжигание меток**
3. В результате переноса вопросов/ответом и проч. мероприятий, у некоторых участников откатились репы - у некоторых по несколько сот.

Не вдаваясь в дискуссии о правильности, неправильности, применимости, допустимости и проч. прочая предлагается:

- откатить примененные технические действия описанные в п.2
- еще раз вернуться к вопросу о сжигании меток и обсудить еще с чувством с толком и расстановкой вопросы поднятые в п.1

**Update**

Пример, потери репутации
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По аналогии, потеря репутации у @IVsevolod за [этот пост](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/714760/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B7%D0%B0-2-3-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0?answertab=votes#tab-top) - потеряно 35*10-2+15=363, отметим, что мало у кого на этом сайте есть ответ с рейтингом 34.

**Ван мор апдейт**

Часто приходят всякие так назовем *товарищи*, которые пишут в чате, каментах или просто имеют ввиду: *а че такого, но падумаешь 100 потерял, че из-за этого хипишь поднимаешь?*

Отвечу просто и односложно: да, я не обеднею от 100 реп, но мне омерзителен сам факт, ровно на пустом месте тырят 100, похоже на то как стянули в общественном транспорте мелочи на 100 рублей, мелочь, но неприятно. Здесь речь не о сумме, не о величине, а в самом факте.

Comment: Поддерживаю и обращаю внимание, что [существует штатный механизм для таких ситуаций](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2480/181100), который к потерям репы не приводит.

Comment: Вопрос-предложение интересный, но не стоит намеренно давать ложную информацию людям. Особенно тем, кто не сильно в курсе данной процедуры. В результате сжигания меток **НЕ удаляются** вопросы. Вопросы удаляются/перемещаются по другим причинам (в принципе Nicolas Chabanovsky описал почему).

Comment: А где я написал, что вопросы удаляются? Я только написал, что при этом теряется честно заработанная репутация

Comment: Было бы неплохо увидеть в вопросе ссылки, подтверждающие откат репутации ("по несколько сот" особенно). И поправить ссылку на чат, с указанием начала дискуссии, в текущем виде от неё мало проку.

Comment: @Barmaley тогда встаёт логичный вопрос - а причём тут сжигание меток? Опять же, при **сжигании меток репутация не теряется**. То есть всё так же информация остается ложной. Как бы то ни было, почему репутация пошла вниз описано в ответе

Comment: @АлексейШиманский или вы прикидываетесь или вы на самом деле (ну вы поняли) - **репутация потерялась** в результате ваших непродуманных действий и точка. При этом откат совершенных действий так и не привел к восстановлению репутации.

Comment: @alexolut отрихтовал вопрос в соответствии с вашими комментариями

Comment: @Barmaley я по-прежнему не вижу потери "нескольких сот" у других участников. Проблема затронула фактически кого-то кроме Вас или нет?

Comment: В вопросе перемешаны мухи с котлетами. Пожалуйста определитесь о чем же все-таки вопрос? (о сжигании меток ИЛИ ошибочном откате репутации)

Answer (score 6):

Причина переноса проста: сообщество [приняло решение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4589/6) о том, что такие вопросы нетематичны для основного сайта, но могут жить на Мете. Более того, ранее в нашей практике были спорные моменты, в результате которых, собственно, и была создана метка [диалоги-о-работе](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5). Тогда мы переносили вопросы с исторической блокировкой, что не вызвало споров. Сейчас же в ходе обсуждения мы выяснили, что камнем преткновения является, как минимум, репутация, снимаемая со всех, кто участвовал в обсуждении ранее допустимого вопроса. Возникает конфликт: вроде бы данный вопрос нетематичен, но репутация была получена ранее честным путем, когда вопросы данного характера были допустимы.

По результатам обсуждения в чате, на данный момент, правильным решением видится оставлять подобные вопрос на основном сайте с исторической блокировкой.

---

К процессу удаления нежелательных меток данный вопрос отношение не имеет, так как удаление нежелательных меток — дело полезное.

Comment: Вопрос был не о правомерности или неправомерности переноса/уничтожения/сжигания меток, а о том, что непродуманные действия привели к потере честно полученных репутаций (в сумме я полагаю речь идет о тысячах), некоторые участники потеряли до 400 баллов. Сейчас изменения откатили, но репы не вернулись.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что потеря репутации возникла именно из-за переноса на Мету, и если бы было простое удаление - она бы осталась в определённых случаях, согласно [ответу](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238) на MSE: *"The post had a score of at least +3; The post has been visible on the site for at least 60 days"*?

Comment: @alexolut Как ни странно, как минимум из [блога](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/06/reputation-and-historical-archives/), именно так и следует.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky вероятно миграция должна работать так же как и удаление. С сохранением репы, в частности если до начала миграции пост долго провисел.

Answer (score 4):

Процесс, который вы почему-то назвали "сжигание меток" (это название фактически вводит в заблуждение, т.к. убирание меток никогда не влияло на изменение репутации) не ставил своей целью лишить кого бы то ни было ранее заработанной репутации. Даже если эта репутация была получена во времена, когда не было никакого *Stack Overflow на русском*. Цель ставилась иная, и об этом достаточно подробно [сказано в ответе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5851/176217) Николая на текущей странице.

Я провёл небольшое исследование и не смог найти каких-либо подтверждений отката репутации у других участников, которые давали ответы на вопрос, из-за переноса которого у вас репутация уменьшилась на 98 пунктов. Т.о. **ваше высказывание**:

> потеря репутации у @IVsevolod за этот пост - потеряно 35*10-2+15=363

**не соответствует действительности**. [Последнее изменение репутации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/11360/ivsevolod?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=1) у участника на текущий момент было 20 июля 2017 года и связано с совсем другими действиями:

> [image: IVsevolod]

Ни о каких потерях 363 речи нет и в помине. Если у вас есть какая-то иная информация на этот счёт, просьба привести подтверждающие это ссылки.

Таким образом, возмущаться надо не самим фактом переноса вопроса, который по правилам Stack Overflow не является онтопичным, а выяснять причину, по которой откат репутации коснулся только вас. Допускаю, что проблема кроется в не совсем корректном переезде базы вопросов/ответов с ХешКода на движок Stack Overflow. В этой части уже были замечены [некоторые нестыковки](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291897/339911).

В связи с этим рекомендую вам оформить соответствующий баг-репорт с более серьёзными метками, чем [нытьё](/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%91) и надеяться на ответ сотрудников Stack Overflow. Для увеличения вероятности ответа вопрос безусловно стоит задать на [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Чтобы увидеть изменения репутации, связанные с удалением вопросов, надо в профиле поставить специальный флажок. Чужие профили показываются всегда без этого флажка. То, что на скриншоте, никак **не показывает, было ли изменение репутации**.

Comment: @Qwertiy у ТС откат из-за **переноса**, а не из-за удаления. Ну и на [графике](https://stackexchange.com/users/3554219/ivsevolod?tab=reputation) тоже не видно.

Answer (score 1):

Как известно, вопросы были перенесены на мету, а потом была сделана попытка их вернуть обратно. Однако, в этой схеме допустили ошибку и получилось совем не то, что хотели:

- Как перестать писать говнокод?
  [Оригинальный вопрос - 4 954 просмотра](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/327030/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4?noredirect=1) - удалён при переносе
  [Вопрос на мете - 22 просмотра](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5844/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4?noredirect=1) - удалён при переносе
  [Новый вопрос после переноса - 229 просмотров](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/714771/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4) - получил историческую блокировку
- Стать программистом гуманитарию за 2-3 года?
  [Оригинальный вопрос - 17 315 просмотров](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/214645/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B7%D0%B0-2-3-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0?noredirect=1) - удалён при переносе
  [Вопрос на мете - 18 просмотров](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5835/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B7%D0%B0-2-3-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0?noredirect=1) - удалён при переносе
  [Новый вопрос после переноса - 195 просмотров](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/714760/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B7%D0%B0-2-3-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0) - получил историческую блокировку

В ближайшее время попробую это исправить.